How to handle zero-padded sequences in 1D CNNs to avoid dependency on padding length?
I am working on a feature prediction task from time series data using the following 1D CNN model:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class My1DCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(My1DCNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1280, 239 * 4)  # Adjust the input features to the correct flattened size

    def forward(self, x, eeg_mask=None):
        if eeg_mask is not None:
            eeg_mask = eeg_mask.unsqueeze(1)
            x = x * eeg_mask
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv5(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Flatten keeping the batch size intact
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 239, 4)
        return x

The model takes a batch of sequences with shape (batch, channel, time) and predicts features with shape (batch, time, feature). To handle variable-length sequences, I zero-padded them and used an eeg_mask to mask the padded parts.
The model trains well and performs well on test data. However, when I input random data using torch.rand_like(x), the model still performs reasonably well. This suggests that the model is leveraging the length of the zero-padded parts as a feature, which is not desired. The model should rely solely on the actual data, not on the length of zero values.
Question: How can I modify my 1D CNN model to ensure it does not depend on the length of the zero-padded parts of the sequences?
Things I Have Tried

GRU with pack_padded_sequence()

I attempted to use a GRU before the CNN and applied pack_padded_sequence() and pad_packed_sequence() for masking. However, for training the CNN, I had to use pad_packed_sequence(~, total_length=239), which required specifying total_length. This led to zero-padding again, causing the subsequent CNN layers to learn patterns based on the length of the zero-padding, which is the issue I want to avoid.
class My1DCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size=32, hidden_size=32, num_layers=1):
        super(My1DCNN, self).__init__()
        # Set up 1D convolutional layers
        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(
            in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1
        )
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(
            in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1
        )
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(
            in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1
        )
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv1d(
            in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1
        )
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv1d(
            in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1
        )
        # Max pooling for 1D
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        # Assuming the size after conv and pooling layers, adjust accordingly
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(
            1280, 239 * 4
        )  # Adjust the input features to the correct flattened size

    def forward(self, x, eeg_mask=None):
        # if eeg_mask is not None:
        #     eeg_mask = eeg_mask.unsqueeze(1)
        #     x = x * eeg_mask
        # Calculate the lengths of the sequences based on the eeg_mask
        if eeg_mask is not None:
            lengths = eeg_mask.sum(dim=1).cpu().int()
            x = x * eeg_mask.unsqueeze(1)
        else:
            lengths = torch.full((x.size(0),), x.size(1), dtype=torch.int64)

        x = x.permute(0, 2, 1)
        # Pack the padded sequence
        packed_input = pack_padded_sequence(
            x, lengths, batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False
        )
        packed_output, _ = self.gru(packed_input)
        gru_output, _ = pad_packed_sequence(
            packed_output, batch_first=True, total_length=239
        )
        gru_output = gru_output.permute(0, 2, 1)
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(gru_output))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv5(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        # Flatten the output for the fully connected layer
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Flatten keeping the batch size intact
        x = self.fc1(x)
        # Reshape if needed, or adjust fc layer output size
        x = x.view(-1, 239, 4)
        return x


Additionally, I tried using mirror padding instead of zero-padding, but it didn't help either. Still the model learns inappropriate and factitious patterns from padding

Reference: I checked this Stack Overflow question about zero-padding a time series for a CNN model with global average pooling, but it didn't help with my issue.
